# What is some synonymic expression for "Cut it out" or "Don't do this"

Tags: expressions

Answer the question as if it is in the case that somebody point a gun at your head.

Comment: cease and desist -  but that would have to be mailed by your lawyer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**at your peril** [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/at+your+peril)

> (do something) at your (own) ˈperil (*often used as a warning*) at the
>   risk of serious danger

As in:

> Drop it ... at your peril!

ps: you best have plan B ready!

Comment: I have always used it oppositely:  “If you don’t drop it it will be at your peril.”